# Java: Printing out the head of a queue using element()

Tags: java, queue

I want to print the head of this queue of names using the element() method but it somehow doesn't.
Can somehow please explain me why it doesn't?

```
package lesson1;
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass1{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Queue <String> strings= new LinkedList<String>();
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of names, n.");
        int n= input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter " +n+ " names");

        for(int i=0;i<n; i++){

            strings.add(input.nextLine());
        }

        for(String object: strings){

            System.out.println(object);
        }

        System.out.println("The name in front of the queue is: " + strings.element());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first element in your Queue is an empty String.
This is why `strings.element()` returns an empty String and you see the output `The name in front of the queue is:`.

To eliminate the empty String add :

```
int n= input.nextInt();
input.nextLine(); // this
```

Explanation: After calling `nextInt`, the next `nextLine` will consume the end of the line that contained the integer that was read, so the first `strings.add(input.nextLine());` will add an empty String to the Queue.

Comment: Thanks!  I got it.. Actually, I have changed it from `strings.add(input.nextLine());` to `strings.add(input.next());` It works fine now..

Comment: But still, I seem to be at loss at the explanation you gave when you said "the `nextLine` will consume the end of the line that contained the integer that was read..." Can you please explain it again?

Comment: @Diksha Suppose you type in 5 and then hit enter. `nextInt` will return 5. The following `nextLine` will read the rest of the line containing the 5, which contains just the new line character, strip the new line character and return an empty String. Only the next `nextLine` will read from the following line.

Comment: Well..What do you mean by "The following nextLine will read the rest of the line containing the 5"? I am sorry for lack of understanding.. I have just started with Java..

Comment: @Diksha I'm referring to the line from which the Scanner reads its input. If, for example, you type 5 followed by the enter key, the first line available for the Scanner contains 5 followed by \n (or \r\n, depending on the OS). The `nextInt` method doesn't read the \n or \r\n. It only reads the 5. Therefore, the next call to `nextLine` will read from the first unread character until it reaches an end of line. Therefore it will read the \n or \r\n. Since the Scanner methods strip new line characters and empty spaces by default, this nextLine will return an empty String.